# Connecting To and Changing A .mdf Database in a Form

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a really simple GUI rpg game for a college project.

The project needs a GUI, Database, and some kind of interactivity, I have the GUI and the interactivity, but I am having a lot of trouble with the database part. I am doing it in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

I am trying to make it so when I click buy on a weapon, it updates the player's stats, which then should update the new stats to the userdata table of the database, but everything I try results in failure.

Files:

```
Form1.cs
Player.cs
Quest.cs
UserDatabase.dbml
DatabaseDataSet.xsd
Database.mdf
Battle.cs
Save.cs
```

The `Database.mdf` has a `UserData` table in it.

Only experience I have with databases is using Data Sources to display an entire table in a form, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to take variable data and place it into a database, or take data from a database and put it into variables.

Here is what I have for code in files. I know my code is terrible and I should be shot for how I'm doing most of the things, but I am only caring about getting the database to work at this point since it is due on Friday the 6th and I have no clue on how to get it to work.

**Updated**
I actually started to figure it out a tiny bit using [this for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
`Form1.cs` Code related to trying to connect and save data to database:

```
 private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Database db = new Database(@"Database.mdf");
            Capstone.Save save = new Capstone.Save()
            {
                name = player.name,
                job = player.job,
                weapon = player.weapon,
                armor = player.armor,
                acc1 = player.accessory1,
                acc2 = player.accessory2,
                gold = player.gold,
                eridium = player.eridium,
                exp = player.exp,
                level = player.level,
                str = player.strength,
                magic = player.magic,
                def = player.defense,
                health = player.health,
                mana = player.mana,
                pots = player.pots

            };
            db.userdata.InsertOnSubmit(save);
            try
            {
                db.SubmitChanges;
            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {

            }


        }
public class Save
    {
        public string name = "";
        public string job = "";
        public int weapon = 0;
        public int armor = 0;
        public int acc1 = 0;
        public int acc2 = 0;
        public int gold = 0;
        public int eridium = 0;
        public int exp = 0;
        public int level = 0;
        public int str = 0;
        public int magic = 0;
        public int def = 0;
        public int health = 0;
        public int mana = 0;
        public int pots = 0;
    }
```

SQL code of `Database.mdf` `UserData` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserData] (
      [name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
      [job]     NCHAR (10)    NULL,
      [weapon]  INT           NULL,
      [armor]   INT           NULL,
      [acc1]    INT           NULL,
      [acc2]    INT           NULL,
      [gold]    INT           NULL,
      [eridium] INT           NULL,
      [exp]     INT           NULL,
      [level]   INT           NULL,
      [str]     INT           NULL,
      [magic]   INT           NULL,
      [def]     INT           NULL,
      [health]  INT           NULL,
      [mana]    INT           NULL,
      [pots]    INT           NULL
  );
```

Comment: Please, make code more minimalistic - remove everything that isn't related to your problem. It is not immediately clear where in C# code you are trying to access DB or something like this.

Comment: -1 because you can't possibly expect me to read all that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using LINQ to SQL (given the DBML file). I see a datacontext class, which is what lets you link to the database, but you're not actually initializing it or using it anywhere.

Your general steps are going to be:

- Instantiate a new datacontext object (Databse in your code).
- Create a new entity object (a UserData object)
- Populate the fields of the UserData object.
- Add it to the DB if it doesn't exist, or update the existing one in
  the DB if it exists.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399398.aspx and its children for more information on exactly what the code should look like.